# Rails: Can't pre-set select input in nested model forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I'm working from Ryan Bates's tutorial on how to do nested forms for associated models: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

I have a model District which has many ElectionRecords, each of which has a string "vote_type", which I'd like to be chosen from a select control in the CRUD form.

I have this line in district.rb:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :election_records, allow_destroy: true
```

And here's my code for views/districts/_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@district) do |f| %>
...
<%= f.fields_for :election_records do |builder| %>
  <%= render 'election_record_fields',  f: builder %>
<% end %>
```

"_election_record_fields" is a partial defined here:

```
<fieldset>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :voting_year %>
    <%= f.number_field :voting_year %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :vote_type %>
    <%= f.select :vote_type, options_for_select([['Presidential', 'Presidential'], 
                                                 ['Senate', 'Senate'],
                                                 ['Governor', 'Governor'],
                                                 ['Attorney General', 'Attorney General'],
                                                 ['Proposition', 'Proposition']
                                                 ], @election_record.vote_type) %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :voting_results %>
    <%= f.text_field :voting_results %>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

I get an error: NoMethodError in Districts#edit, "undefined method `vote_type' for nil:NilClass". Makes sense, because @election_record isn't defined due to the use of nested attributes.

But replacing @election_record with f doesn't work either: if I do that, the NoMethodError is "undefined method `vote_type' for ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007fe85ba9cef0".

How do I use the form builder object to give me either the first option if there's been no associated record saved, or the value of the current record being edited?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
<%= f.fields_for :election_records do |builder| %>
  <%= render 'election_record_fields',  f: builder %>
<% end %>
```

With

```
<%= f.fields_for :election_records, @district.election_records do |builder| %>
  <%= render 'election_record_fields',  f: builder %>
<% end %>
```

Then in your `_election_record_fields` partial you can access the specific election_record using `f.object.vote_type` instead of `@election_record.vote_type`.

Comment: Then in your _election_record_fields should read as `Then in your _election_record_fields partial`